# Динамические псевдонимы полей в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Возможно ли в MySQL добавлять динамически псевдонимы полей?

**Пример**:
3 таблички, из 1 вытаскиваем определенные поля, а 2 другие по join-у. В одной значения, в другой коды полей:

```
SELECT ... 
       table_1.value, 
       table_2.code, 
FROM table
LEFT JOIN `table_1` ON `table_1`.table_id = `table`.id
LEFT JOIN `table_2` ON `table_2`.ID = `table1`.table_2_id
WHERE ...
```

На выходе 6 одинаковых с позиции table записей с разными полями table_1.value и table_2.code.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы на выходе была одна строка c дополнительными 6 полями:

```
table_field_1 table_field_2 ... table_1_value_as_field_name * 6
```

То есть, одна строка на выходе и 6 полей из сджоиных таблиц, который имеют псевдонимы в виде table_2.code и значения table_1.value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587600/how-to-select-column-value-as-column-name-with-conditions-in-sql-table

Comment: Лучше на клиенте разворачивайте в горизонталь. На SQL это будет процедура, которая сначала получит названия колонок (т.е. выполнит запрос один раз для получения их), а потом сформирует динамический SQL, который выполнит то же самое второй раз, но уже в виде запроса который по ссылке выше

Comment: В принципе, я так и предполагал, что не получиться так сделать. Интересно, а что будет быстрее, выполнить несколько запросов или бегать по результату выборки на клиенте используя php?